# Jupyter doesn't recognize super(). Is there a fix?

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

When attempting to call a static method in a superclass I can run code like:

```
super().doSomething()
```

in standard Python 3, but the same code doesn't run in Jupyter. The error message is

```
super(): no arguments
```

I've tried

```
super(SubClass).doSomething()
```

but then the error message is

```
name 'SubClass' is not defined
```

even though the code is running in a class named `SubClass`.

What does work is

```
SuperClass.doSomething()
```

That's fine, but it means that making `SubClass` a subclass of `SuperClass` is not relevant.

All this is happening in static methods in both `SubClass` and `SuperClass`.

Am I missing something, or is there a fix for this?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are running your code with wrong kernel in Jupyter? For example: https://github.com/jupyter/jupyter/issues/270

Jupyter is just is just a shell, it runs some version of python to evaluate your code.

Comment: The same thing happens when I run the code on Jupyter installed on my computer (by conda) and on Google's colabratory. As far as I can tell, it's a Jupyter issue.